# 3 tables on ipad with different data

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview

Im trying to implement 3 different table views that load 3 different arrays of information,
In some forum I read that I could use the .tag to differentiate the tables and use conditionals to load the data,
I tried 
changing the name of the table 
in identity /name of the xib to my table,

and use

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    //---try to get a reusable cell---
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //---create new cell if no reusable cell is available---
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

 /*
  //---set the text to display for the cell---
  NSString *cellValue = [listOfMovies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.text = cellValue; */

 if (tableView.tag == 1) {
  //Deal with table 1 - contains 5 sections
  cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
 } else if (tableView.tag == 2) {
  //Deal with table 2 - contains 1 section
 cell.textLabel.text = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
 }
 // cell.textLabel.text = [array3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
 else {
  cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
 }

 return cell;
}
```

to change the cell content to show the other array
but is not working (long shot!)
so, How to define this .tag for my tables
also, I want the same for row (count) and sections 1
for all the tables,
so shall I just leave them like that??
I have the 3 tables showing the same array at the moment,

thank you so much!

Comment: If I just change for example the 0 in tag in the xib (view/tag)for any table for a 2 (to show my other array),  I get > Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)'

Answer (score 0):

Um, haven't tried this, but I'd be inclined to look into associating each table view with it's own unique UITableViewDataSource instance. That way they do not have to be all coded in the same class and everything becomes simpler. Not sure how you would go about assembling this, but it should be too hard to work out I would think.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-complicating things. In one of my apps I have one table view controller for three tables. The interface definition is something like:

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UITableView *leftTable;
    IBOutlet UITableView *centerTable;
    IBOutlet UITableView *rightTable;

    ...
```

Then, in each of the delegate methods, I check to see which table it is before performing the relevant action or returning the relevant result. For example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (tableView == leftTable) { 
        return [self.leftItems count]; 
    } else if (tableView == centerTable) {
        return [self.centerItems count];
    } else {
        return [self.rightItems count];
    }

}
```